# How to trigger a anynomous function with parameters Javascript

Tags: javascript

Today I was at job interview - and I had been presented with a task.
I have never encoutered such a function, so there it is:

Write down a function which after triggering like this:

```
console.log('hello'.repeatify(3))
```

returns

```
hellohellohello
```

I was trying to create an empty object and append a method repeatify, however i just don't know how to trigger it just with 'hello'.

Maybe i should change console.log method?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wasn't that really hard. You have to make a new function for `String.prototype` and use `repeat()` function to multiply given string by given argument.

```js
String.prototype.repeatify = function(count){
  return this.repeat(count);
};

console.log('hello'.repeatify(3))
```

Comment: Thank you kidn sir!

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own prototype methods for every object, but you shouldn't do it with native objects:

```js
String.prototype.repeatify = function(num) {
  return this.repeat(num);
}

console.log('hello'.repeatify(3));
```

[read more about this bad practice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Didn't know of the repeat function on javascript strings. That's the better solution probably. But why the heck would they ask for reimplementing an already existing function in the job interview :D

Comment: Well, who knows - they might just wanted to test if you know about that... But as written and linked above, don't use that pattern on native objects like String, Array, ... @user3691763

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.repeatify = function(amount)
{
  var endString = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
  {
    endString += this;
  }
  return endString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify String's prototype object:

```
String.prototype.repeatify = function (A) {
   var i = 1;
   var a = this;
   while (i++ < A) {
      a += this;
   }
   return a;
}

console.log('hello'.repeatify(3));
// outputs hellohellohello
```

There are mixed feelings on modifying the prototype of built in objects.  I have both that it is just fine and that it is a bad practice.  Personally I try to avoid it and prefer defining a standalone function to modifying the prototype of something I didn't create.