# added new methods for prototype of array

Tags: javascript

```
    let journal = [..............];
        //need sort by key time
        function sortByStatus(){
          return    journal.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.fly_status - b.fly_status;
            });
        }

        function sortByTime(){
            return    journal.sort(function(a, b) {
                console.log(  new Date( a.start_datetime).getTime()  );
                return new Date( a.start_datetime).getTime()
 - new Date(  b.start_datetime).getTime();
            });
        }
```

**How can i do this logic:**

`journal.sortByStatus().sortByTime()`.....some other methods of array ?

**I can added those methods only journal array not all array in my page ?**

Comment: Just like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513268/how-to-trigger-a-anynomous-function-with-parameters-javascript/42513309#42513309, just change *String* into *Array* and the logic ofc.

Comment: Don't do it. `journal` is an array, you should not add custom methods to it.

Comment: @Bergi Should not what? Add new methods to the Array.prototype?

Comment: @Kinduser correct. One reason is that they might collide with functions added later to the Ecmascript standard or by frameworks you decide to use in the future

Comment: @JanDvorak What about learning purposes? I have done it hundred times and as you can see, I'm still alive.

Comment: @Kinduser you can do all sorts of unclean stuff in learning projects, and run away before they have the time to bite you. BTW, Ruby recently added a keyword that does a similar thing, but only in the lexical scope defined by the keyword, so that your definitions wouldn't throw off other code. No such protection exists in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it could be to define your own object. This example doesn't allow for chaining the methods but you could call them sequentially:

```js
let Journal = function(list){
  this.list = list || [];
  
  this.sortByStatus = function(){
    return this.list.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.fly_status - b.fly_status;
    });
  }

  this.sortByTime = function(){
    return this.list.sort(function(a, b) {
      return new Date( a.start_datetime).getTime() - new Date(  b.start_datetime).getTime();
    });
  }
}

let journal = new Journal([
  {fly_status:50, start_datetime: 5},
  {fly_status:5, start_datetime: 50}
]);

console.log(journal.sortByStatus());
console.log(journal.sortByTime());
```

To allow for chaining, return the object itself after the method is complete (although with sorting, you'd probably just pick one sort or the other):

```js
let Journal = function(list){
  this.list = list || [];
  
  this.sortByStatus = function(){
    list.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.fly_status - b.fly_status;
    });
    return this;
  }

  this.sortByTime = function(){
    list.sort(function(a, b) {
      return new Date( a.start_datetime).getTime() - new Date(  b.start_datetime).getTime();
    });
    return this;
  }
    
}

let journal = new Journal([
  {fly_status:50, start_datetime: 5},
  {fly_status:5, start_datetime: 50}
]);

console.log(journal.sortByStatus().sortByTime().list);
```